# how does is it possible that post is accessible in my controller?

Tags: angularjs

how is it possible that i can do `$scope.post = post;` and that i did not have to do `$scope.post = posts.post;`

app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['templates','ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })
   .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
          return posts.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

postCtrl.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',
    'post',
    function($scope, posts, post){
        $scope.post = post;
        $scope.addComment = function(){
          if($scope.body === '') { return; }
          $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
          });
          $scope.body = '';
        };
}]);
```

Comment: You passed post as a parameter to your controller (and therefore injected it), why woudn't it be possible?

Comment: where is post defined though? i would think i would do this $scope.post = posts.post instead

Comment: I'm not following you. You're injecting post into your controller. I assume you put it there for a a reason. If you inspect it in the debugger, what is it? It has to be defined somewhere, otherwise injecting it would trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple.

You wrote in declaration of your `posts` state:

```
resolve: {
    post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
        return posts.get($stateParams.id);
    }]
}
```

You inject in this function your `posts` service and make a call (to some API, whatever). This function returns `promise`. Property `resolve` in state declaration at first will wait for resolving all promises which has been written in there. And after that it will inject the results of all resolved promises into the controller.

Lets take a look on your controller:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
       .controller('PostsCtrl', [
           '$scope',
           'posts',
           'post',
           function($scope, posts, post){
               $scope.post = post;
               ...
           };
}]);
```

On injection section we can see `posts` - injected service. Also `post` - which will be a resolved promises which came from resolve section of your state.

It means that you don't have to call your `posts` service again, because it was already called before instantiating the controller. You probably don't need to inject this service at all.

I hope I clarified that and it will help you to understand.